# Proposal: new Necromancer-like gold badge

Tags: discussion, badges, badge-request

[necromancer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/necromancer) is awarded if you ["answer a question more than 60 days later with score of 5 or more"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/17/necromancer). It has been "awarded 433915 times".

There's no corresponding gold badge for some reason. Let's have it, for example, for answering a question more than a year later with score of 50 or more (disclaimer: I would be eligible for one as well; so what?). <s>***update 3: 2000 days ⁄ 10 votes** seems to be the way to go* (and I personally wouldn't be eligible)</s> *edit 4:* nah, the original suggestion was totally in line with the other badges like the Populist, producing roughly the same number of eligible users... or maybe make it *two years / 50 votes*, since the silver badge is for *two months / 5 votes*; a nice symmetry there! and I haven't checked whether I'd be eligible then, so there.

Is this a good idea? What could the appropriate name be?

*"Gravedigger"*? (gold digger... get it?)

---

*update:* this is a duplicate of [No gold badge for revival/necromancer/… pattern?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/97455/no-gold-badge-for-revival-necromancer-pattern) (asked 6.5 years ago, was **very well received**; it's interesting to compare how the attitudes of this community have changed... or perhaps the community itself has changed). Thanks to [BDL](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/2579738/bdl) for [pointing it out](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/364659/proposal-new-necromancer-like-gold-badge?noredirect=1#comment565262_364659). Can't vote it a dupe as it's on a different meta (wasn't it the same meta back then?).

*update2:* That question is very old, the stats in it are out of date. It was asked in 2011. **It makes sense to include the new, up-to-date stats here:**

According to [this query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/39389/gold-revival-necromancer-badge) by [EdoDodo](https://data.stackexchange.com/users/6277):

```
 Requirements:
  181 days     366 days     366 days     731 days    1000 days    2000 days    2000 days
  25 score     25 score     50 score     100 score    40 score     20 score     10 score

 Eligible users:
   44079        34971        16703         4109        8420         2625         6368
```

Many top users are eligible for more than one such badge, in each of the above queries.

For comparison, the other answers-related gold badges currently have:

```
Great answer     (100+)                      5.9k   users
Populist         (outvote the 
                  accepted answer)          16.2k   users
Reversal         (20+ ans on -5 q)             284  users
Unsung hero      (0 score, accepted)        18.4k   users
Tenacious
    (silver)     (0 score, accepted)        47.2k   users
```

***update 3:*** Looks like ***2000 days ⁄ 10 votes*** is sufficiently far-fetched for a gold badge, makes a fitting number of people eligible *(6368)*, and at the same time rewards people for answering old questions without demanding too high a vote count on the answer, so makes it more likely for new answerers to get one too. (FYI *1000 days ⁄ 10 votes* makes 36600 users eligible).

<sub>(As an additional bonus for all the naysayers, I personally wouldn't be eligible (a motivation that I was accused of having, [in the comments](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/364659/proposal-new-necromancer-like-gold-badge?noredirect=1#comment565255_364659)).)</sub>

Comment: Can you link the question/answer, for science? I'm fascinated by how such a thing could take place!

Comment: all I can take from this questions is "I feel I have done something to earn a gold badge, can I get one?"

Comment: @msanford https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2211990/how-to-implement-an-efficient-infinite-generator-of-prime-numbers-in-python/10733621#10733621

Comment: @WhatsThePoint So I began writing a response explaining how "I'm unsure this points to a 'significant contribution' as defined by the gold badge class", but the more I think about it, I feel it's in a similar category to `unsung-hero`. That said, other badges like `guru` have no bronze or gold equivalent. Also, thanks for the link (I suppose I could have searched for  it myself).

Comment: Related: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/97455/no-gold-badge-for-revival-necromancer-pattern/254753#254753

Comment: @msanford I believe the concept criteria of this badge is completely different to the unsung hero badge, the unsung hero badge in my eyes is awarded as a bittersweet as in "here you've put good effort in to not get much credit, here have a reward for your effort" but the idea for this badge is "so you have earned at least 500 rep from one answer already, have a second reward" this seems to me completely different from the unsung hero badge

Comment: @WhatsThePoint Mostly thinking aloud; I agree with your point.

Comment: @WhatsThePoint You can't say that you've earned 500 rep from an answer with a score of 50.  You could have earned 0 rep from it, thanks to the rep cap.

Comment: @WhatsThePoint as is well known, whatever ***you*** are getting from anything in life is first of all ***you***. (it's a general "you" of course, but it seems to apply).

Comment: @BDL thanks for the link; I only searched through [tag:badge-request] on *this* [meta] when asking (and didn't find anything related).

Comment: Personally, when I'm accused of (more or less) loathsome motivations I feel great reticence to justifying myself.

Comment: @msanford apparently, it happened for 16703 users, many of them more than once. I've updated the question. and 4098 users for 733 days/100 score (!).

Comment: 50 upvotes is a little too much IMHO, it makes it similar to the "great answer" badge (which requires 100) and possibly skews it towards the more popular questions or tags. How many of those 4098 users also have a "great answer" badge? [Disclaimer: I made some alternative proposals and came here thanks to EdoDodo's link at https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/97455/no-gold-badge-for-revival-necromancer-pattern?noredirect=1#comment1002504_97455 ]

Comment: @Nemo I've updated the question with more sample queries and stats for other gold badges to compare with. Interesting results!

Comment: @WillNess Thanks, that's useful. The total number that would be awarded is fine, but I was curious about the overlap between the recipients of the various badges. In my opinion it's more interesting to add a new badge if we reward users who are otherwise underappreciated by other badges. :) (But it's just me.)

Comment: @Nemo that's why I asked the question, to get the opinions of others. :) to your point, we could go with the **2000 days / 10 points**. I've updated the question again. thanks for the feedback!

Comment: @WillNess wow, and even with a 2000 days requirement there would be something like 100k [good unanswered questions](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=is%3Aquestion+created%3A..2000d+answers%3A0+score%3A0..+closed%3Ano) to work on!

Answer (score 4):

I would propose that we don't increase time for gold necromancer equivalent. But instead require the answer to become an accepted answer with say 20 upvotes.

I think the hardest part is getting to 5. I have friends that confessed they never look at anything but the top answer. Going off `zero` is the hardest thing when other answers already exist. Then things would happen naturally with time, provided the answer is useful.

Or we can get even stricter, thus making the badge a real honor:

- answer to question at least 60 days old
- question must already have an accepted and upvoted answer
- your answer must reach score of at least 20
- your answer must become accepted

This is true necromancy IMO. Not like answering a question that has no good answers yet. I haven't done any analysis as you. But I think this should be rare enough. Or some numbers can be adjusted.

Comment: looks good to me, except for the requirement that the answer becomes accepted.  too many a question asker cease being engaged with the site altogether, can't be relied upon to make a sound judgment. I'd accept this answer otherwise. Similarly with the 2nd requirement: without the accepted part. Just having an upvoted answer is enough. Or maybe require it to have at least 5 votes already. How's that sound?

Comment: hmm, reading last comments from Nemo, why exclude the questions that had no attention whatsoever? reviving them and getting 20+ votes, now *that* would be the true necromancy, no?!

Comment: @WillNess, that would be a resurrection IMO :) I would prefer it to have another gold badge. Perhaps more upvotes required. I won't oppose it though as long as stack team accepts gold necromancer in whatever way.